# Redirection or Name server addresses

Tags: redirect, dns-hosting, dnsmasq

I asked my new webhost:

"I need my domain languagematerial.com to point to my new host: http://languagematerial.altervista.org/ so I must know which are the name server addresses in altervista. I asked my previous host (ipage) where my domain languagematerial.com is parked to do the change or to allow me to do it. Apparently they made a modification, but it's not working right, because my Android cellphone cannot resolve www.languagematerial.com and now takes me to a Internal Server Error page. What can I do?"

The AlterVista staff answered: "you can't point directly via DNS to an AlterVista account.

You can only use a redirect from your domain."

I no longer have an ipage web hosting account... so how to achieve this redirection (and preferably, with address masking)? Could I ask ipage to enable a redirect for free? Or I will be forced to pay ipage or some other company to enable a permanent redirect (with address masking?). Anyway, isn't redirection a behavior included when you "buy" a domain?

So how to proceed? What's the best way to get what I need with the minimal cost? Thanks. Carlos Botero

Comment: proabaly you could have a subdomain A record for languagematerial.altervista.org in your altervista.org control panel with a valid static IP. Use that static IP for languagematerial.com in your control panel @ A record , and create a CNAME record for www that points to langugagematerial.com - Its a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you still should be able to access your domain's DNS settings if you bought it.

Or you can ask your previous hosting provider to initiate domain transfer to your new hosting provider. Most likely it will cost you, the price will be the same as you would renew your domain for 1 year or so.

To be honest, this is your best option because you will be able to create/edit/delete DNS records for your domain as much as you like or need.

Cheers!